# Hyperledger fabric chain code invoke returns the error

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain

```
root@27e4f0c27a0e:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer# peer chaincode instantiate -o orderer.example.com:7050 --tls --cafile /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem -C myChannel -n marbles -v 1.0 -c '{"Args":["init"]}' -P "OR ('Org1MSP.peer','Org2MSP.peer')" 
2018-10-01 05:46:15.704 UTC [chaincodeCmd] checkChaincodeCmdParams -> INFO 001 Using default escc 
2018-10-01 05:46:15.704 UTC [chaincodeCmd] checkChaincodeCmdParams -> INFO 002 Using default vscc     
root@27e4f0c27a0e:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer# 
peer chaincode invoke -o orderer.example.com:7050 --tls --cafile /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem -C myChannel -n marbles -c '{"Args":["initMarble","marble1","blue","35","tom"]}'
```

Error: endorsement failure during invoke. chaincode result:

Comment: I understand that you are following the BYFN manual. Have you changed something? Are you sure that you have both of your Peers running? Could you execute in the CLI the "docker ps" command?

Comment: Yes, sir my both peers are running.I am trying to create docker-compose files of peers, orderer, cli and up the containers  on single pc with one organization.After successfully installed chaincode on peers it didn't gives any logs for successfully instantiate chaincode on peers.

Comment: Could you paste the logs that you get in the CLI when you execute de invoke? On the other hand, have you created something in the configtx.yaml file?

Comment: when I execute the invoke function of chaincode logs are:- root@eaaf9b6b63e2:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer# peer chaincode invoke -o orderer.example.com:7050 --tls --cafile /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem -C my -n user -c '{"Args":["createUser","9876543210","abc@gmail.com","Abc","22","123456"]}'
Error: endorsement failure during invoke. chaincode result: <nil> But when I check chaincode on peer it is already instantiated on channel.

Comment: Probably it would be because you have something created earlier. Could you try removing the containers and volumens, and trying to execute all the process again? Or you could try to upload a new version of your chaincode

Comment: m also did this. Remove all containers and volumes but again it gives same issue.Also try to install chain code with new version but same issue faces again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181279/discussion-between-dipanshu-jindal-and-urko).

Answer (score 1):

Add `sleep 20` into the starting of your `chaincodeInvoke` function on scripts/utils.sh line no 297